# Is there any working game server manager for Linux?

Tags: webserver, games, panel, free-software

I'm running a machine on Ubuntu Server 17.04 and hosting various servers for various games (Source, Minecraft, etc). Is there any **free** game server manager that I can access from another machine (whether remote or LAN) that will provide me with a console, multiple game servers support and a user-friendly interface for my friends?

I understand how to install software through the package manager and even compile some, and in addition, I'm a programmer. But somehow, I can't find **any** game server manager that actually works properly (and most of the time: even installs..).

I tried:

- Ajenti

  - Successfully installed but was extremely glitchy on my end and had too many errors for one of my friends to even do anything past logging in. In addition, there was no instructions, documentation, forum post, forum question or easy command to uninstall it whatsoever and at this point it was such a pain that I had to reinstall the whole OS.
- Pterodactyl

  - Documentation was completely half-assed, following it to the letter and even going into the external links given and following those instructions along the way wouldn't allow me to properly install it.
- PufferPanel

  - Instructions were **extremely** vague, I entered every given commands and carefully followed the instructions and yet, whenever I try to connect to it, I still see the nginx welcome screen. In addition, it's a pain to uninstall (though still much easier than Ajenti).

Thank you! Sincerely.

Side note: I know how to port forward and general networking, that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As it is, I'd suggest connecting via SSH and managing the system either through command line or with the help of x11 forwarded graphic applications. Open-ssh server is all you need to install on the host, and for client computers, I'd suggest the Mobaxterm client. Of course, configuration is going to take a while, but once set, it will be a robust solution.

For server managing, I can only point you in this direction:
https://gameservermanagers.com/

Half assed documentation is a mainstay when dealing with linux based systems, majority of developers expect the user to be already familiar with their solution, it seems.